# Apache24 on windows returns 'It works' only instead of the virtual hosts

Tags: windows, apache-2.4, mod-wsgi

I have configured Apache 24 with mod_wsgi on windows 2016 server for my Django applications and deployed three websites with different IP addresses. I have also configured ssl certificates for each domain and everything is working fine until somehow the system shuts-down due to power and when the system is back Apache returns only "It works" for all domains unless I restart the Apache service manually. why is this happening please help. I have to restart Apache server every time I lose power.

I have also placed ssl files for one domain inside conf folder named server.crt,server.ca-bundle and server.key

below is my virtual host configuration

```
LoadFile "C:/<virtual environment directory>/Scripts/python38.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/<virtual environment directory>/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp38-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "C:/<python installation directory>/python38"
WSGIPythonPath "C:/<virtual environment directory>/Lib/site-packages"

NameVirtualHost domain1.com:80
<VirtualHost domain1.com:80>
  ServerAlias www.domain1.com       
  ServerName domain1.com
  Redirect permanent / https://domain1.com
</VirtualHost>

 

<VirtualHost domain1.com:443>
ServerAlias www.domain1.com      
ServerName domain1.com
ServerAdmin admin@gmail.com
 
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile "C:/<SSL certificate direcory>/<cirtificate-name>.crt"
SSLCertificateChainFile "C:/<SSL certificate direcory>/<cirtificate-name>.ca-bundle"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/<SSL certificate direcory>/<cirtificate-name>.key"

Alias /static/ "C:/<project root directory>/static/"
  <Directory "C:/<project root directory>/static">
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

Alias /media/ "C:/<project root directory>/media/"
  <Directory "C:/<project root directory>/media">
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/<project root directory>/fbpidi_portal/<wsgi file name>.py"
  <Directory "C:/<project root directory>/fbpidi_portal">
    <Files <wsgi file name>.py>
      Require all granted
    </Files>
  </Directory>



ErrorLog "C:/<project root directory>/logs/apache.error.log"
CustomLog "C:/<project root directory>/logs/apache.custom.log" common
</VirtualHost>


NameVirtualHost domain2.com:80
<VirtualHost domain2.com:80>
  ServerAlias www.domain2.com       
  ServerName domain2.com
  Redirect permanent / https://domain2.com
</VirtualHost>

 

<VirtualHost domain2.com:443>

ServerAlias www.domain2.com       
ServerName domain2.com
ServerAdmin admin@gmail.com
 
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile "C:/<SSL certificate directory>/<certificate-name>.crt"
SSLCertificateChainFile "C:/<SSL certificate directory>/<certificate-name>.ca-bundle"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/<SSL certificate directory>/<certificate-name>.key"

Alias /static/ "C:/<project root directory>/static/"
  <Directory "C:/<project root directory>/static">
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

Alias /media/ "C:/<project root directory>/media/"
  <Directory "C:/<project root directory>/media">
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/<project root directory>/<project name>/wsgi.py"
  <Directory "C:/<project root directory>/<project name>">
    <Files wsgi.py>
      Require all granted
    </Files>
  </Directory>



ErrorLog "C:/<project root directory>/logs/apache.error.log"
CustomLog "C:/<project root directory>/logs/apache.custom.log" common
</VirtualHost>



Listen 8080

<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:8080>

ServerAlias 0.0.0.0      
ServerName 0.0.0.0
ServerAdmin admin@gmail.com


Alias /static/ "C:/<project root path>/static/"
  <Directory "C:/<project root path>/static">
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

Alias /media/ "C:/<project root path>/media/"
  <Directory "C:/<project root path>/media">
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/<project root path>/<app name>/wsgi.py"
  <Directory "C:/<project root path>/<app name>">
    <Files wsgi.py>
      Require all granted
    </Files>
  </Directory>



ErrorLog "C:/<project root path>/logs/apache.error.log"
CustomLog "C:/<project root path>/logs/apache.custom.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Without seeing the actual configuration we can't even guess. Also, there is no such thing as a "Windows 10 server". Please state the actual versions your are using.

Comment: it looks for me like that you try to hide that you using windows 10 as a server. that's off topic and against the ToS. which paths has been used for the vhosts?

Comment: No I'm using windows server 2016 I wrote 10 by mistake